# Stress tensor of a rope in equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

First of all, let me say that I'm not a student of physics but of mathematics, so please be comprehensive. I'm currently studying continuum mechanics.

As an example of applications of Cauchy stress tensor equations, analyzing a rope in equilibrium, with both ends fixed to walls, under only gravity, my book states:

> $$\frac{dT(s)}{ds}=\rho f(s)$$ where $\rho f(s)$ is the linear density
>    of external force and $s$ is the arclength parameter

Now, my question is: shouldn't it be $-\rho f$?

By Cauchy equations, we know that $$\nabla\cdot T=\rho(a-f)$$ (where $a$ is acceleration), and thus in equilibrium we should have, since $a=0$, $$\nabla\cdot T=-\rho f$$?

I thought that this could have been for a different definition of $T$ in this problem, it being the tension, and not the stress tensor, but I still don't se why there isn't a minus

Diagram: [image]
(The problem is, in fact, concerning a suspended bridge)

Comment: @Chemomechanics done

Comment: @Chemomechanics $f$ is defined "The linear density of external forces acting on the rope", while I don't understand what it means that $f$ never points in the direction of $s$, being $s$ a parameter, and thus a scalar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking online, I found the english version of the book, in which, in fact, is written $-\rho f$. I post here the corrected version of the problem for completeness
[image]